# libceph: kernel client remains invalid connection retry

Tags: ceph

After ceph server's ips change, kernel libceph client keeps connection retry to old monitor ips. could someone please has experience to resolve the problem, namely cleaning kernel errors up?
kernel log errors resemble below:

```
[Fri Dec 21 15:11:42 2018] libceph: mon1 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
[Fri Dec 21 15:11:43 2018] libceph: mon1 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
[Fri Dec 21 15:11:44 2018] libceph: mon1 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
[Fri Dec 21 15:11:46 2018] libceph: mon1 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
[Fri Dec 21 15:11:50 2018] libceph: mon1 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
[Fri Dec 21 15:11:58 2018] libceph: mon1 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
[Fri Dec 21 15:12:12 2018] libceph: mon0 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
[Fri Dec 21 15:12:13 2018] libceph: mon0 10.*:6789 socket closed (con state CONNECTING)
```

Comment: linux kernel client: libceph keeps connection retry

Comment: Did you edit the ceph.conf on the clients as well so they point to the correct IPs? Did you change DNS settings so they reflect the new IPs?